# Optimised way for my Linq or Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a Linq query where I need to fetch all distinct currency codes. Currency code USD is to be shown first and rest will be sorted alphabetically.

I tried like this by breaking it to two queries like this and it works fine:

```
var currencies = context.DbCurrencies.DistinctBy(x => x.CurrencyCode)
                .Where(c => c.CurrencyCode != null).ToList();

var result1 = currencies.First(c => c.CurrencyCode == "USD");

var result2 = currencies.OrderBy(c => c.CurrencyCode)
              .Where(c => c.CurrencyCode != "USD").ToList();

return result1.Concat(result2).ToList();
```

Is there any way that I can get this with a single expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
var currencies = context.DbCurrencies
        .DistinctBy(x => x.CurrencyCode)
        .Where(c => c.CurrencyCode != null) // add filter to query
        .AsEnumerable() // execute query against database
        .OrderBy(c => c.CurrencyCode != "USD") // Move USD to the top of the list
        .ThenBy(c => c.CurrencyCode) // Then order by currency codes
        .ToList();
```

P.S :
 To tell the truth, the extension mehtod's name is `Distinct`. But, I thought that you can use your own extension method.

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ipgWUJ

Comment: It shows everything in ascending order.But I want USD 1st then others as per ascending order.

Comment: Then replace `.OrderBy(c => c.CurrencyCode != "USD")` by `.OrderBy(c => c.CurrencyCode == "USD")`.

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra Could you please tell me, what must be result in case of such currecies:  `"EURO", "USD", "AZN", "Rubl"`

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra In my case the result will be: `USD, AZN, EURO, RUBL`

Comment: "USD","AZN", "EURO", "Rubl"

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra Then, it seems taht my answer is right. Not??

Comment: But it shows in this order "AZN", "EURO", "Rubl","USD"

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra I have added fiddle link to my answer. Please run it, It shows USD in the first place.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it works fine I was using your previous given code not the last one.Thanks

Comment: I thinkm it's needn't to call AsEnumerable, sql-server can sort this way, AFAIK.

Comment: @Backs May be, I didn't work with Ms SqlServer, so I thought that it might be better to write code, which I really know will work in any case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [custom comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
return context.DbCurrencies.DistinctBy(x => x.CurrencyCode)
    .Where(c => c.CurrencyCode != null).OrderBy(c => c.CurrencyCode, new CurrencyCodeComparer()).ToList();
```

You need a new `CurrencyCodeComparer` class but you can reuse it:

```
public class CurrencyCodeComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        if (x == "USD")
            return -1;
        if (y == "USD")
            return 1;
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```